# is it ok to declare javascript variable in if block and use it outside the block?

Tags: javascript

In most languages I would write

```
declare var1 = undefined
if (condition) {
 var1 = value1
}
```

but in javascript, it seems its allowed to write

```
if (condition) {
  let var1 = value1
} else {
  var1 = value2
}
```

Am I misguided on this?

Comment: `it seems its allowed to write` Not allowed if you're using `let` - it has block scope (along with `const`. are you sure you're not thinking of `var`?)

Comment: I would recommend just declaring the variable without setting it before all the conditions (ie, "let var;"), and setting it if you need to. One more line of code, but no issues and better readability imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, a variable can be declared after it has been used.
In other words: a variable can be used before it has been declared.
Hoisting is JavaScript's default behavior of moving all declarations to the top of the current scope (to the top of the current script or the current function).

So:

```
x = 5
// ... some other code ...
var x
```

will be translated to:

```
var x;    
x = 5
// ... some other code
```

But it would only work this way if you used `var` to declare variable. If you use `const` or `let` it wouldn't work, because variables and constants declared with `let` or `const` are not hoisted.

Declaring variables using `let` or `const` is [preferred](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75) way in modern javascript.

Comment: Are let and const not hoisted to the top of their block scope? I thought they were

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can when you use var.

Not when you use `let` and `const` because they are block scoped.

**Example for var**

```js
if (true) {
 var var1 = 1
}
console.log(var1);
```

**Example using let**

```js
if (true) {
 let var1 = 1;
}

console.log(var1)
```

**P.S :-** In JS world using `var` is considered as bad coding practice.You should avoid using it until there is something you can't do with `let` and `const`.

Comment: As I figure out from many resources including the Kyle Simpson's book YDKJS: "Programmers should give a priority to use var,  let,  cost in that order specifically. let is not the new var, we still have to use var where variables need to be there for the whole scope of the code"

Comment: @Shakespear well that you can do by defining the `let` in outermost scope.

Comment: Of course, we can define the let in outermost scope., but still... I think let shines in for loops and so, but we don't always have to replace var with let keyword as a new habit.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's completely bad idea. If you want to use JavaScript variable both inside and outside of the if statement you can do it by declaring it outside the if statement.

```
let var1 = value1;
if (condition) {
  var1 = value1
} else {
  var1 = value2
}
```

This way you will only create a block scoped variable. But, if you use `var var1 = value1` then it will declare globally scoped variable which is not what you wanted most probably. 
To learn more about how variables works in javascript, you can checkout this awesome [article](https://wesbos.com/let-vs-const/). Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `let`, but NOT in **Strict Mode**!

```
'use strict';
var condition = false;

if (condition) {
  let var1 = 42;
  console.log(var1);
} else {
  var1 = 43;
  console.log(var1);
}
// ReferenceError: var1 is not defined
```

It's recommended to declare `var1` outside the scope of `if` statement:

```
'use strict';
var condition = false;
var var1 = 42;

if (condition) {
  console.log(var1);
} else {
  var1 = 43;
  console.log(var1);
}
// => 43
```