# Checkbox checked true/false inside another function

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a 'get code' function which I have writing to  but will use Clipboard API after we figure this out! I want to update the string value of a const based on whether a checkbox is checked. If checked the CSS vars are prepended with the namespace "typecsset-", e.g., --_**typecsset-**text-typeface, if not, the namespace const is blank, e.g., --_text-typeface.

Search "$HELP" for the spot I'm stuck. Thanks!

```js
        // main element (target) for typesetting output
        const typesetOutput = document.getElementById("typesetting");

        // font size input and sub label
        const textSizeRemInput = document.getElementById("text-size-rem");
        textSizeRemInput.addEventListener("input", updateTextSize);
        const textSizePxOutput = document.getElementById("text-size-px");

        function updateTextSize(event) {
            typesetOutput.style.setProperty(
                "--_text-size",
                `${textSizeRemInput.value}rem`
            );
            textSizePxOutput.textContent = parseFloat(textSizeRemInput.value * 16).toFixed(1);
        }



        // font leading input and sub label
        const textLeadingInput = document.getElementById("text-leading");
        textLeadingInput.addEventListener("input", updateLeading);
        const textLeadingPxOutput = document.getElementById("text-leading-px");

        function updateLeading(event) {
            typesetOutput.style.setProperty(
                "--_text-leading",
                `${textLeadingInput.value}`
            );
            textLeadingPxOutput.textContent = parseFloat(textLeadingInput.value * 16).toFixed(1);
        }



        // text measure input
        const textMeasureRemInput = document.getElementById("text-measure-rem");
        textMeasureRemInput.addEventListener("input", updateMeasure);
        // draggable label (parent) container
        const textMeasureResize = document.getElementById("text-measure-resize");

        // update measure CSS prop
        function updateMeasure(event) {
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
                "--_text-measure",
                `${textMeasureRemInput.value}rem`
            );
            // update width of draggable label (parent) container
            textMeasureResize.style.width = `${textMeasureRemInput.value}rem`;
        }
        // watch for width changes to draggable label (parent) container
        let observeMeasure = new ResizeObserver(function (mutations) {
            // convert to rem
            const sizeInRem =
                mutations[0].contentRect.width /
                parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).fontSize);
            // update measure CSS prop
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--_text-measure', sizeInRem + 'rem');
            // update input value
            textMeasureRemInput.value = sizeInRem.toFixed(1);
        });
        let draggable = textMeasureResize;
        observeMeasure.observe(draggable);


        // theme switcher
        const invertButton = document.getElementById("invert");
        invertButton.addEventListener("click", invertTheme);
        const prefersDarkScheme = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
        // CSS does the rest

        function invertTheme(event) {
            if (prefersDarkScheme.matches) {
                document.body.classList.toggle("light-theme");
            } else {
                document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme");
            }
        };



        // $HELP get code function
        const preElementRepo = document.getElementById("code");
        const copyButton = document.getElementById("copy");
        //const textFontOutput = textFontInput.value;
        const textFontOutput = "'Cormorant Garamond'";
        const textSizeOutput = textSizeRemInput.value;
        const textLeadingOutput = textLeadingInput.value;
        const textMeasureOutput = textMeasureRemInput.value;
        const nameSpacedCheckbox = document.getElementById("namespaced");
        const nameSpace = 'typecsset-';

        copyButton.addEventListener("click", getCode);
        function getCode(event) {

            // $HELP
            if (nameSpacedCheckbox.checked) {
                const nameSpace = 'typecsset-';
            } else {
                const nameSpace = '';
            }

            preElementRepo.textContent = `:where(html) {\n    /* Get your head tag font emebed codes at https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Name+Name */\n    --_${nameSpace}text-typeface: var(--${nameSpace}text-typeface, ${textFontOutput});\n    --_${nameSpace}text-size: var(--${nameSpace}text-size, ${textSizeOutput}rem);\n    --_${nameSpace}text-leading: var(--${nameSpace}text-leading, ${textLeadingOutput});\n    --_${nameSpace}text-measure: var(--${nameSpace}text-measure, ${textMeasureOutput}rem); \n\nbody {\n    font-family: var(--_${nameSpace}text-typeface);\n    font-size: var(--_${nameSpace}text-size);\n    line-height: var(--_${nameSpace}text-leading);\n    inline-size: var(--_${nameSpace}text-measure);\n}`;

            alert(`CSS copied to the clipboard. Paste away!`);
        }
```

```css
* {
    /* layout debugger */
    outline: deeppink dotted 0.5px;
}

:where(html),
:root {
    --_text-size: var(--text-size, 1rem);
    --_text-leading: var(--text-leading, 1.5);
    --_text-measure: var(--text-measure, 80rem);
    --_color-light: var(--color-light, #fff);
    --_color-dark: var(--color-dark, #000);
    --_color-neutral: var(--color-neutral, gray);
    --_space: var(--space, 1rem);
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: var(--color-light);
    color: var(--_color-dark);
}

main {
    font-size: var(--_text-size);
    line-height: var(--_text-leading);
    inline-size: var(--_text-measure);
}

button,
input {
    font: inherit;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

    body {
        background-color: var(--_color-dark);
        color: var(--_color-light);
    }

    #theme::after {
        content: '#FFF on #000';
    }

}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {

    #theme::after {
        content: '#000 on #FFF';
    }

}

body.dark-theme {
    background-color: var(--_color-dark);
    color: var(--_color-light);
}

body.dark-theme #theme::after {
    content: '#FFF on #000';
}

body.light-theme {
    background-color: var(--_color-light);
    color: var(--_color-dark);
}

body.light-theme #theme::after {
    content: '#000 on #FFF';
}




/* layout ptimitives */
.center {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    margin-inline: auto;
    max-inline-size: var(--_text-measure);
    padding-inline-start: 3rem;
    padding-inline-end: 3rem;
}

.cluster {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: var(--_space);
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}

.vertical-rhythm {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.vertical-rhythm * {
    margin-block: 0;
}

.vertical-rhythm *+* {
    margin-block-start: calc(var(--_space)/3.14)
}



/* utils */
.resizable {
    resize: inline;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.justify-content\:space-between {
    justify-content: space-between;
}

/* visually hidden, but not from screen readers: https://gist.github.com/Heydon/c8d46c0dd18ce96b5833b3b564e9f472 */
.hide {
    clip-path: inset(100%) !important;
    clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px) !important;
    height: 1px !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    width: 1px !important;
}
```

```html
<body class="center vertical-rhythm">

    <nav class="cluster">

        <label class="vertical-rhythm">
            <h2>Size</h2>
            <input id="text-size-rem" name="text-size" data-uom="rem" type="number" value="1.00" step="0.01" min="0.5" max="3.0">
            <h4>rem: <span id="text-size-px">16.0</span>&#8198;px</h4>
        </label>

        <label class="vertical-rhythm">
            <h2>Leading</h2>
            <input id="text-leading" name="text-leading" data-uom="" type="number" value="1.50" step="0.01" min="0.01" max="10">
            <h4>Unitless: <span id="text-leading-px">24.0</span>&#8198;px</h4>
        </label>

        <label class="vertical-rhythm">
            <h2>Ground</h2>
            <button id="invert">Invert</button>
            <h4 id="theme"></h4>
        </label>

        <label class="vertical-rhythm">
            <h2>Code</h2>
            <button id="copy">Copy</button>
            <h4>CSS<input id="namespaced" type="checkbox" checked><label for="" style="font-size: .75em;">&nbsp;Namespaced</label></h4>
        </label>

    </nav>

    <label id="text-measure-resize" class="resizable vertical-rhythm">
        <h2>Measure</h2>
        <input id="text-measure-rem" name="text-measure" data-uom="rem" type="number" value="80" step="0.1" min="10" max="150">
        <div class="cluster justify-content:space-between">
            <h4>rem</h4>
            <h4>drag&nbsp;&searr;&nbsp;</h4>
        </div>
    </label>

    <main id="typesetting">
        <p>The density of texture in a written or typeset page is called it*s <em>color</em>. This has nothing to do with red or green ink; it refers only to the darkness or blackness of the letterforms in mass. Once the demands of legibilty and logical order are satisfied, <em>eveness of color</em> is the typographer's normal aim. And color depends on four things: the design of the type, the spacing between the letters, the spacing between the words, and the spacing between the lines. None is independent of the others.</p>
        <p>Anything from <em>45 to 75</em> characters is widely regarded as a satisfactory length of line for a single-column page set in a serifed text face in a text size. The 66-character line (counting both letters and spaces) is widely regarded as ideal. For multiple column work, a better average is 40 to 50 characters.</p>
    </main>
    </body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is it ok to declare javascript variable in if block and use it outside the block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800529/is-it-ok-to-declare-javascript-variable-in-if-block-and-use-it-outside-the-block)

Comment: Sort of…still learning. Thank you.

Comment: It's fine, we've all been there. I recommend you read https://javascript.info/, it's a great starting point.

Comment: @Seblor AMAZING resource 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of a `const` is the block containing the declaration. So if you use it in an `if` block it will not be visible outside the `if`. Use a `let` declaration outside the `if`, then assign the variable inside the `if`.

```js
function getCode(event) {
  let nameSpace = '';
  // $HELP
  if (nameSpacedCheckbox.checked) {
    nameSpace = 'typecsset-';
  }

  preElementRepo.textContent = `:where(html) {\n    /* Get your head tag font emebed codes at https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Name+Name */\n    --_${nameSpace}text-typeface: var(--${nameSpace}text-typeface, ${textFontOutput});\n    --_${nameSpace}text-size: var(--${nameSpace}text-size, ${textSizeOutput}rem);\n    --_${nameSpace}text-leading: var(--${nameSpace}text-leading, ${textLeadingOutput});\n    --_${nameSpace}text-measure: var(--${nameSpace}text-measure, ${textMeasureOutput}rem); \n\nbody {\n    font-family: var(--_${nameSpace}text-typeface);\n    font-size: var(--_${nameSpace}text-size);\n    line-height: var(--_${nameSpace}text-leading);\n    inline-size: var(--_${nameSpace}text-measure);\n}`;

  alert(`CSS copied to the clipboard. Paste away!`);
}
```

Comment: Yay! That was easy. Thank you, Barmar!

Comment: I update the snippet but it errors in Stackoverflow's env. It works locally though!

Comment: You shouldn't put the fix in the question. Readers need to see the difference between what you wrote and my answer.

Comment: I see you rolled it back. Thank you.